# I deleted my Terraria world without a backup. Is it possible to get it back?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I accidentally deleted my Terraria world, and I don't have a backup. Is there any possible way to get it back without jailbreaking?

I am playing on an iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but there's no way of recovering it, the files are already deleted.